# ggplot - using annotate across facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, rect, facet-wrap, annotate

This is a basic question but haven't been able to find the answer on here. I am creating a figure with ggplot from the following (overly simplified) data:

```
df.for.graph <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5,nrow = 8)), c("xp","yp","loc","cong","emotion"))
df.for.graph$xp <- c(948.7, 977.2, 1023.4, 953.3, 979.4,936.3, 911.6,877.2)
df.for.graph$yp <- c(923.0, 893.0, 294.9, 241.5, 898.6, 960.9, 154.4, 263.4)
df.for.graph$loc <- as.factor(c("Bottom", "Bottom", "Top", "Top", "Bottom", "Bottom", "Top", "Top"))
df.for.graph$cong <- as.factor(c("Incongruent","Congruent","Incongruent","Congruent", "Incongruent","Congruent","Incongruent","Congruent"))
    df.for.graph$emotion <- as.factor(c("Angry", "Angry", "Angry", "Angry", "Happy","Happy", "Happy","Happy"))
```

My call to ggplot is as follows:

```
ggplot(df.for.graph,aes(x=xp,y=yp,color=loc,shape=cong)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,4)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "yellow")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1920, by = 160), limits=c(0,1920)) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1200, by = 80), limits=c(1200,0)) +
  labs(shape = "Congruence", color = "Probe Location",x = "X Position", y = "Y Position") +
  facet_wrap(vars(emotion),nrow=2,ncol=1) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size=20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold",size=15, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold",size=15, color="black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=2),
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold",size=20),
        legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", size=15),
        legend.title = element_text(colour = "black", size=15)) +
  annotate("rect",xmin=0, xmax=1920, ymin=0, ymax=599,alpha=.4) +
  annotate("rect",xmin=0, xmax=1920, ymin=602, ymax=1200,alpha=.4)
```

This results in the following: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNTxv.png)

However I want the call to annotate to leave a line between the two rectangles on both facets of the plot. Currently it only leaves a line between the two on the top (Angry) facet. I thought that supplying the rect coordinates without specifying facets should draw the same two rectangles on each facet of the plot...

Any thoughts on how to make the bottom facet look like the top one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `annotate` `rect` lines show up for me (if the plot is big enough along vertical axis). If you expand the plot size does it show up? Or use different numbers for ymin and ymax (try 590 and 610 instead of 599 and 602)?

Comment: Ah, yeah if I change the ymin and ymax so the space is bigger it does show up! However, it still doesn't show up in the bottom facet if I keep the original values, even when I full screen the image. Weird, but I can move forward with the larger interval instead - thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of it displaying it properly on the device, i suggest you save it to a png or pdf. First save plot as object:

```
g1 = ggplot(df.for.graph,aes(x=xp,y=yp,color=loc,shape=cong)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,4)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "yellow")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1920, by = 160), limits=c(0,1920)) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 1200, by = 80), limits=c(1200,0)) +
  labs(shape = "Congruence", color = "Probe Location",x = "X Position", y = "Y Position") +
  facet_wrap(vars(emotion),nrow=2,ncol=1) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size=20),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold",size=15, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=20),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold",size=15, color="black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=2),
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold",size=20),
        legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", size=15),
        legend.title = element_text(colour = "black", size=15)) +
  annotate("rect",xmin=0, xmax=1920, ymin=0, ymax=599,alpha=.4) +
  annotate("rect",xmin=0, xmax=1920, ymin=602, ymax=1200,alpha=.4)
```

And save:

```
ggsave(g1,file="g1.png",width=12,height=12)
```

[image]

Comment: I agree that would be my recommendation as well.